# Quick Actions greyed out?

Tags: 8.1, action-center

The quick actions in my phone's action center are greyed out and I can't use them:

[image]

I have a Nokia Lumia 521 with Windows Phone 8.10.14219.341. I tried a hard reset and it still doesn't work. It was working a few days ago but it randomly stopped working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you go to Settings -> notifications+actions, can you reset the quick actions?

Comment: no it still does not show, It shows that the QUick Actions are set to wifi,cellular,bluetooth,rotation lock. I also tried changing them to something else and changing them back and no change

Comment: If a hard reset doesn't work you could try the Lumia Software Recovery Tool before going to a service center.

Comment: Mine 920 does this briefly after a reboot but a couple of seconds it's back to work.